# VS 2017 - Xamarin not debugging apps only on my phone

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

The apps were debugging on my phone before, I had uninstalled the app but it didnt fully uninstall and didnt allow me to debug, So I used adb commandline to uninstall app fully. Before I used the command line, I went into apps section in my phone settings and uninstalled **"Xamarin.Support"** or "**Xamarin.Android**" in the apps section. After that any app, (tried making a new vs xamarin file) no app will debug on my android phone now.

I have tried turning Developer settings off and on, usb debugging on and off. Tried making a new vs xamarin file. All of these debug on Android simulator and on another phone but not on mine! When I try to debug any app on my phone. It builds, takes some time. and crashes immediately after starting. 
I am thinking it is the "Xamarin.Support" app that I deleted of my phone that is effecting this. Please help!
[image: error I get after it crashes]

The other phone that the debugging is working on, I went into their, went into apps in settings and searched xamarin. It had **"Xamarin.Android API-27..."** My phone also had something similar to that but I uninstalled it accidentally, and I dont know how to get it back to make it debug on my phone if that was indeed the issue.

Comment: **I went into apps section in my phone settings and uninstalled "Xamarin.Support" or "Xamarin.Android" in the apps section.**, I don't know how you do, but you can try Disable "Use fast deployment (debug mode only)" in Android project -> Properties -> Android options -> Packaging

Comment: Hey, I tried that aswell because disabling it fully installs everything. However for some reason, it did not install the missing package on my phone. I am very sure now that it is the reason the app wont build on my phone. I tried to make a new file and used another phone (samsung device), it loaded fine because they had the Xamarin.Android API-27/28/29 Support. But yes, I do not know why it is not reinstalling the packages on my phone after I build.

Comment: ,Anything update?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, Unfortunately it never fixed the problem. Like I said I deleted something in my phone and after that I can never install apps from vs. I had to use my friends phone to install the app and show to the teacher.